# Soft as a rock bed on the moon, seeking source & quote

Tags: story-identification, gravity

I recall reading a book maybe 20 years ago; two people on the moon went to a low budget overnight accommodation.  The beds are stone shelves.

One says to the other something like

> in the moons low gravity a flat stone bed feels softer than the
>   softest feather bed on Earth

in the morning the other agrees with the first.

I think it might have been a Heinlein, work but not sure. Looking for the name of the work and the quote.

Comment: There is a sequence in *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls* that has four characters sleeping on a simple stone shelf, but there is no dialog supporting the idea that any one is skeptical about the prospect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the quote is

> At one-sixth gee a rock shelf is softer than a foam mattress in Iowa. I went to sleep quickly.

from *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls* by Robert Heinlein.  The story is told in the first person and so this was an internal observation of Richard Ames.

Comment: Thank you; posted to [space](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/do-you-need-a-mattress-on-the-moon) to see if it is true.